# Replace each row based on the string match and column value

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a dataset like this

```
dt <- data.table(Score = c(0.33,0.34,00.3, -0.22, 0.232), 
                 Id2 = c("0/0","0/1","1/0","0/0","0/0"), 
                 Kps = c("0/1","0/0","1/1","0/1","0/0"), 
                 Inr = c("0/0","0/1","1/1","0/0","0/1"))
```

I need to replace the values of each row based on the Score column as like this

- If "0/0" or "1/1" then `Score * 2`
- If "1/0" or "0/1" then `Score`

Usually, it can be done by using the base function like this

```
dt$Id2 <- dt$Score * 2
```

But here I have to consider each row and I have around 1000 columns so it can be only done with loop

The expected output

```
Score  Id2    Kps    Inr 
0.330  0.66   0.330  0.66
0.340  0.340  0.68  0.340
0.300  0.300  0.6   0.6
-0.220 -0.44 -0.22 -0.44
0.232  0.464 0.464  0.232
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` -way solution.
It uses a `data.frame` and makes it longer in a first step. Then with `case_when` the different conditions were implemented.

`pivot_wider` brought it back to a wider format.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dt<- data.frame(Score = c(0.33,0.34,00.3, -0.22, 0.232), 
                Id2=c("0/0","0/1","1/0","0/0","0/0"), 
                Kps=c("0/1","0/0","1/1","0/1","0/0"), 
                Inr=c("0/0","0/1","1/1","0/0","0/1"))


dt |> 
  pivot_longer(-Score) |> 
  mutate(value = case_when(
    value == '0/0' | value == "1/1" ~ Score *2,
    value == '1/0' | value == "0/1" ~ Score 
  )) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>    Score    Id2    Kps    Inr
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  0.33   0.66   0.33   0.66 
#> 2  0.34   0.34   0.68   0.34 
#> 3  0.3    0.3    0.6    0.6  
#> 4 -0.22  -0.44  -0.22  -0.44 
#> 5  0.232  0.464  0.464  0.232
```

Comment: Using `%in%` is more concise: `case_when(value %in% c("0/0", "1/1") ~ Score * 2, TRUE ~ Score)`

Comment: @ˋDarren Tsai  yes, this is right.

Answer (score 3):

As the input is `data.table`, here is one approach with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 dt[, (names(dt)[-1]) := lapply(.SD, \(x)
    fcase(x %chin% c("0/0", "1/1"), Score *2,
    x %chin% c("1/0", "0/1"), Score)), .SDcols = -1]
```

-output

```
> dt
    Score    Id2    Kps    Inr
1:  0.330  0.660  0.330  0.660
2:  0.340  0.340  0.680  0.340
3:  0.300  0.300  0.600  0.600
4: -0.220 -0.440 -0.220 -0.440
5:  0.232  0.464  0.464  0.232
```

---

Or another option is to make use of named vector

```
keyval <- setNames(c(2, 2, 1, 1), c("0/0", "1/1", "1/0", "0/1"))
dt[, (names(dt)[-1]) := lapply(.SD, \(x) Score *keyval[x]), .SDcols = -1]
```

-output

```
> dt
    Score    Id2    Kps    Inr
1:  0.330  0.660  0.330  0.660
2:  0.340  0.340  0.680  0.340
3:  0.300  0.300  0.600  0.600
4: -0.220 -0.440 -0.220 -0.440
5:  0.232  0.464  0.464  0.232
```

---

Or create a count of 1s and 0s to multiply

```
library(stringr)
dt[, (names(dt)[-1]) := lapply(.SD, \(x) Score * 1 + 
   (str_count(x, "0")!= 1)) , .SDcols = -1]
> dt
    Score   Id2    Kps   Inr
1:  0.330 1.330  0.330 1.330
2:  0.340 0.340  1.340 0.340
3:  0.300 0.300  1.300 1.300
4: -0.220 0.780 -0.220 0.780
5:  0.232 1.232  1.232 0.232
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr::across()`, you can apply a function across multiple columns. It supports [tidy selections](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html) so that you can cleverly select variables based on their names or properties.

```r
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  mutate(across(-Score, ~ ifelse(.x %in% c("0/0", "1/1"), Score * 2, Score)))

#     Score    Id2    Kps    Inr
# 1:  0.330  0.660  0.330  0.660
# 2:  0.340  0.340  0.680  0.340
# 3:  0.300  0.300  0.600  0.600
# 4: -0.220 -0.440 -0.220 -0.440
# 5:  0.232  0.464  0.464  0.232
```

---

A tricky way

```r
dt %>%
  mutate(across(-Score, ~ Score * (.x %in% c("0/0", "1/1") + 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using matrix multiplication:

```
# like @akrun using a named vector for conversion, to avoid ifelse/case/switch:
keyval <- setNames(c(2, 2, 1, 1), c("0/0", "1/1", "1/0", "0/1"))

#convert and make the matrix, then multiply
matrix(keyval[ as.matrix(dt[, -1 ]) ] * dt[[ 1 ]], ncol = ncol(dt) - 1)
#        [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
# [1,]  0.660  0.330  0.660
# [2,]  0.340  0.680  0.340
# [3,]  0.300  0.600  0.600
# [4,] -0.440 -0.220 -0.440
# [5,]  0.464  0.464  0.232
```

Benchmark using a bigger dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#bigger data
n = 1000
set.seed(1); dt <- data.table(cbind(
  Score = runif(n),
  data.frame(matrix(sample(c("0/0", "0/1", "1/0", "1/1"), n * n, replace = TRUE), ncol = n))))
```

Matrix multiplication should give 3-7x improvement compared to *dplyr*:

```
m <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  matrix = {
    matrix(keyval[ as.matrix(dt[, -1 ]) ] * dt[[ 1 ]], ncol = ncol(dt) - 1)
  },
  dplyr1 = {
    dt |> 
      pivot_longer(-Score) |> 
      mutate(value = case_when(
        value == '0/0' | value == "1/1" ~ Score *2,
        value == '1/0' | value == "0/1" ~ Score 
      )) |> 
      pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
  },
  dplyr2 = {
    dt %>%
      mutate(across(-Score, ~ Score * (.x %in% c("0/0", "1/1") + 1)))
  })

print(m, unit = "relative")
# Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  matrix 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
#  dplyr1 7.697692 8.468686 7.279598 8.071069 7.652855 3.423847   100
#  dplyr2 3.862794 3.708899 3.399736 3.560082 3.687698 2.096620   100
```